# Django: querying new objects from corrupted model always returns IndexError

Tags: django, model

One of my models is acting strangely. If there are any objects, and I try to access them in any way (including in the admin interface or in the shell) even if they have just been created, I get an IndexError.

Here's example commands in the shell:

**>Path.objects.all().delete()**

**>Path.objects.all()**

[]

**>path = Path(title="test")**

**>path.save()**

**>path**

repr(xxxx.models.Path at 0x7f1601f79910>) failed: IndexError: list index out of range>

I know this isn't enough information to figure out what is happening, but I'm not sure at all what this is related to, so if anyone has seen anything like this, please let me know what other information I should include.

Just in case, here is the model:

```
class Path(models.Model):

  title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
  nodes = models.ManyToManyField(Node, related_name="nodes",through='PathNodeRelationship')

  def __unicode__( self ):
    nodes = self.nodes.all()
    return nodes[0].title + " - " + nodes[len(nodes)-1].title
```

I had been working with the save override previously, but deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It clearly shows that the line that is returning the error is:

```
return nodes[0].title + " - " + nodes[len(nodes)-1].title
```

Don't index the nodes directly. Try to determine if there are any elements in the node with code something similar to this:

```
nodes[0].title if nodes else None
```

Comment: oh my goodness what a STUPID mistake. I thought it was something to do with the save.